# How to find the size of an array in postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, size

Is there any way to find a size of an array?

For Example,

```
CREATE TABLE example (id integer[]) ;

INSERT INTO example VALUES ( '{}');

INSERT INTO example VALUES ( '{5,6,7}');
```

From this, is there any possibilities to get a result like following,

```
size

0

3
```

Answer (score 246):

As vyegorov mentioned, `array_length` will do the trick.  Or if you know that the array is 1-dimensional (which is likely) and are running PostgreSQL 9.4 or higher, you can use `cardinality`:

```
SELECT cardinality(id) FROM example;
```

Comment: If anyone can mention the major difference in using array_length and cardinality that would be great

Comment: `cardinality` returns the number of all the elements in a single or multidimensional array. So `select cardinality(ARRAY[[1,2], [3,4]]);` would return `4`, whereas `select array_length(ARRAY[[1,2], [3,4]], 1)` would return `2`. If you're counting the first dimension, `array_length` is a safer bet.

Comment: This also works for an array saved in a field with `text` type, while `function array_length(text[]) does not exist` ;)

Comment: @ZiaUlRehmanMughal also array length of an empty array unexpectedly evaluates to `null` and not `0` whereas `cardinality` returns what you'd expect. No idea what they were thinking with that logic.

Comment: I wonder why this is called `cardinality`... Something like `array_size` would be more  intuitive IMO

Comment: **Important difference:** when the array is empty (i.e. length is zero), `cardinality(id)` returns 0, but `array_length(id,1)` returns NULL. So for 1-dimensional arrays cardinality is almost always what you want.

Comment: @Hiroki Cardinality is jargon from database theory. Just like the terms Relation and Tupel where a normal person would say Table or Row.

Answer (score 118):

It's trivial [reading docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE):

```
SELECT array_length(id, 1) FROM example;
```

Comment: Do you know what is the second parameter of the function `array_length`. Didn't find that info in docs.

Comment: @suzanshakya, the length of the requested array _dimension_ ツ

Comment: This will return `null` and `3` instead of `0` and `3` for the OPs example. Definitely should promote use of `cardinality` when accepting an answer as it's easier to use and less unexpected (I imagine 99.999% use of arrays are single dimensional)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356546/what-is-the-second-argument-in-array-length-function

Answer (score 21):

Assuming the dimension of the array will always be 1 isn't something I feel comfortable with, so I went with the following:

```
SELECT coalesce(array_length(id, 1), 0) as size FROM example;
```

It's been... at least a decade, but we used to do a lot with `coalesce` and it was pretty handy. Maybe I'm reaching for it out of comfort?

Answer (score 8):

Had to use array_upper in postgres 8.2.

Comment: Life saver. As almost all posts out there are using array_length() assuming people are on postgres 9+ ;(