# What is the second argument in array_length() function?

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Postgresql 9.4 has [functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE) for array. One of them is `array_length(anyarray, int)`. It get two argumetns.

What is the second argument? In all examples it has value `1`. But nowhere says what it is.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

That's array's *dimension*.

Consider an example with a 2D array 3×2:

```
array_length(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 1) ---> 3
array_length(array[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]], 2) ---> 2
```

The size of the first dimension is 3; the size of the second dimension is 2.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you give me a link to documentation where i can read this?

Comment: @HaruAtari Unfortunately, the documentation for postgresql is somewhat scarce in comparison to the wealth of features supported by that RDBMS. Some features are documented only in passing, providing only a hint of what is going on. This function is a perfect example: the documentation to which you link says "returns the length of the *requested array dimension*", without an explanation that "requested dimension" is the second parameter or even an example showing a multi-dimension array.