# Postgres SQL: Query doesn't return data with ANY() clause when array is empty

Tags: postgresql

There is postgres sql query, shown below:

```
Select agencyId, SUM(open),
   from agencies 
   where agency_id= 100 and agency_platform = any(@platformIds) 
   GROUP BY agencyId;
```

If platformIds list is empty then this query doesn't return any data, and on the other hand below query data with no issues:

```
Select agencyId, SUM(open), 
    from agencies 
    where agency_id= 100 
    GROUP BY agencyId;
```

any thoughts?

Comment: It’s behaving as designed - the `any` check  returns false. Perhaps add a condition to only check the `platformIds` if there *are* any?

Comment: @stuartd, I have tried this 
Select agencyId, SUM(open) from agencies where agency_id= 100 and case when array_length(@platformIds, 1) > 0 then agency_platform = any(@platformIds) 
else true end GROUP BY agencyId;

but it says ERROR: syntax error at or near "array_length". Any clue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188756/how-to-find-the-size-of-an-array-in-postgresql